# Python Data frame: Create New Column that Conditionally Concatenates String Values from 1 or 3 Other Columns

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements, concatenation

**Goal: Create new column that outputs strings based on value in original column**

Below is my data frame table.  I want to create the new column highlighted in yellow.

[image]

Below is my business logic:

```
1. If value in 'Cat_Priority_1' = 'Cat_1' then the new column ('Cat_Priority_1_Rationale') is equal to the string values in 'Age_Flag', 'Salary_Flag', and 'Education_Flag' columns.  
2. If value in 'Cat_Priority_1' = 'Cat_3' then the new column ('Cat_Priority_1_Rationale') is equal to the string values in 'Race_Flag'
```

This is the code I tried, but it didn't work:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: use apply function on dataframes

Comment: can you be more specific?  A code sample I can reference please?

Comment: I'll write an answer for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and access it through the pandas library with pd.np.where, which acts like an if statement:

```
df['Cat_Priority_1_Rationale']  = pd.np.where(df['Cat_Priority_1'] == 'Cat_1',
                                           df['Age_Flag'] + ";" + df['Salary_Flag'] + ";" + df['Education_Flag'],
                                           df['Race_Flag'])
```

Answer (score 0):

apply function is used to iterate over the columns of the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2014', '2015'], 'quarter': ['q1', 'q2']})
df['period'] = df[['Year', 'quarter']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
```

gives this dataframe

```
  Year   quarter  period
0  2014      q1  2014q1
1  2015      q2  2015q2
```

Or you can send each row to a separate function that handles the if condition and returns the concatenated string.

Comment: this is not quite what I'm looking for ... you don't have the conditional element in there

Comment: apologies...I'm new to python...I need some code examples to work with

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can directly implement your business logic.

```
>>> def bus_log(row):
...     if row['Cat_Priority_1'] == 'Cat_1':
...         result = []
...         result.append(row['Age_Flag'])
...         result.append(row['Salary_Flag'])
...         result.append(row['Education_Flag'])
...         result = ';'.join(result)
...         if result.startswith(';'):
...             result = result[1:]
...         return result
...     elif row['Cat_Priority_1'] == 'Cat_3':
...         return row['Race_Flag']
...     elif ....: ## another condition could go here
...         ## calculate a result
...         return result
...     elif ....: ## another condition could go here
...         ## calculate a result
...         return result
...     else:
...         return ''
... 
>>> df['Cat_Priority_1_Rationale'] = df.apply(bus_log, axis=1)
```

There are two points I should mention: (1) You should clear away instances of NaN from your data in favour of empty strings before your do this. (2) I suspect an error in the third row of your data, in the 'Salary_Flag' value.

Comment: thank you for the code above; in my real data set I actually need multiple elif statements ; can you update your code to show me how to do multiple elif statements?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this. Broadcasting is usually faster and more readable than iterating over rows. The last line exploits the fact that `False * s == ''` and `True * s == s` for any string `s`.

```
bs = df.Cat_priority_1 == 'Cat_1'
s1 = df.Race_Flag
s3 = df.Age_Flag + ';' + df.Educ_Flag + ';' + df.Salary_Flag
df['new_col'] = bs * s1 + (1 - bs) * s2
```